# remote debugging tomcat in intelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I know that there are tons of posts about this topic, but none of them seem to help me.

So what I am trying to do is enable the tomcat remote debugging tool in intelliJ 2017.2.3 Ultimate edition. I am running intelliJ on a windows machine and tomcat 8 on an ubuntu machine on the same network.

I've mapped the tomcat webapp folder to an smb share for deployment, which seems to work fine.

However I can't seem to get the debugging or JMX working... at least not both at the same time.

currently my setenv.sh file looks like this:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=1043,server=y,suspend=n"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=0.0.0.0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1044 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

and if i run `netstat -lp | grep <tomcat-pid>`:

```
tcp 0 0 *:1043 *:* LISTEN 4363/java
tcp6 0 0 [::]:8009 [::]:* LISTEN 4363/java
tcp6 0 0 [::]:http [::]:* LISTEN 4363/java
tcp6 0 0 [::]:1044 [::]:* LISTEN 4363/java
tcp6 0 0 [::]:47381 [::]:* LISTEN 4363/java
tcp6 0 0 [::]:https [::]:* LISTEN 4363/java
tcp6 0 0 [::]:56544 [::]:* LISTEN 4363/java
tcp6 0 0 localhost:8005 [::]:* LISTEN 4363/java
```

but when I try to deploy with intelliJ i get the following error:

```
Error running 'run on remote'
Unable to connect to the 192.168.1.181:1044, reason:
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I've tried changing the address in the setenv.sh file to 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1 and 192.168.1.181, but nothing seems to work.

So does anyone know what it is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @ochi so at one point I have connected to the server on that port from windows, so reasonably it shouldn't be a firewall thing right?

Comment: @munHunger Use telnet to verify: `telnet 192.168.1.181 1044` on your Windows machine (you may need to [install telnet](https://kb.ctera.com/article/how-to-open-a-telnet-session-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-os-16.html) as it's not available by default).

Comment: different ports might be open.  it could be that port 1044 is not

Comment: try to elimiate if it might be a firewall issue. On the server try `telnet 0 1043` or `telnet 0 1044`. This way you know that the service is running. If they are then you know its network issue.

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: @ZimboRodger I think that I did... was a long time ago :) If I remember correctly the way I did it was rather hacky where you create a "remote" task in intellij that builds and deploys to remote. For some reason the remote task works better than the remote tomcat/jboss tasks

Comment: @munHunger I have an application in my local Tomcat server and I want to debug it with Intellij. But I don`t have source code of this application. Could you please suggest my some article which can help me solve this task?

Comment: If you don't have the source then you can't really debug it in intelliJ... You could try to decompile the class files load them into intelliJ and then start the debugger, but I would guess that this is more difficult than it is really worth